# Oracle alter table insufficient privileges

Tags: sql, oracle, permissions, privileges, database-administration

I have just installed oracle 12c and then I am trying to grant user various rights.

I am logged in as system and I had given rights for `create user` which worked. However, while granting rights for `alter table` it gave me error

`ORA-00990: missing or invalid privilege`

Researching on this problem brought me to another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19216392/insufficient-privileges-when-creating-tables-in-oracle-sql-developer?s=807886a2-f4d6-4a96-b256-3b36c5e700d0) on SO. The Comments on this post indicated that it is because I am not logged in as `GLOBAL` user. However I don't know how to log in as `GLOBAL` user.

Do I have to create one ?

Is there any alternative solution ?

Comment: What account are you logged on and what command are you trying to execute ?

Comment: The post you linked to is not really related; in that case `GLOBAL` was a specific schema they were trying to create an object in, and the error was from the `create table` command, not from the `grant`.

Comment: I am logged into system account and i'm trying to execute `grant alter table to foo;`

Comment: It was my mistake as @AlexPoole said, creating any table gives you alter rights on it. i was just trying to follow accepted answer on [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912781/oracle-11g-statements-to-create-new-user-and-grant-privileges). However, i was trying to give `alter table` to a `user` instead to a `role`.

Comment: @pdevel - you can't grant `alter table` to a role either, so that answer is wrong *8-)

Comment: O.o strange! Still that guy accepted it as answer :\

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no `ALTER TABLE` privilege. The valid privileges are [listed in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/statements_9013.htm#SQLRF55037).

If you have `CREATE TABLE` then you can create and alter your own table. To alter the definition of a table in another schema you'd need the `ALTER ANY TABLE` privilege.

Curiously [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/network.121/e17607/authorization.htm#DBSEG99918) does refer to `ALTER TABLE`:

> For example, to create a trigger on a table, the user requires both the `ALTER TABLE` object privilege for the table and the `CREATE TRIGGER` system privilege.

The [`ALTER TABLE` command prerequisites](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/statements_3001.htm#i2096214) also say:

> The table must be in your own schema, or you must have `ALTER` object privilege on the table, or you must have `ALTER ANY TABLE` system privilege.

In this context it's a bit clearer; '`ALTER` object privilege' means that you've been directly granted `ALTER` on the table by its owner, rather than via the `ALTER ANY TABLE` system privilege, as in:

```
create table t42(id number);
grant alter on t42 to user2;
```

Then `user2` would be able to `alter table t42 ...`, or create a trigger on it (for example), but not any other tables.

Comment: Correct. It Works! i was instead trying to execute `grant alter table to username`.i wasn't specifying WHICH table could he alter. Also i was unaware of the fact that you automatically get `ALTER` rights on table you create.

Answer (score 3):

Trying to figer out what is the problem I guess you execute something like

```
SQL> conn system/***@***
Connected.
SQL> grant alter table to scott;
grant alter table to scott
      *
error in line 1:
ORA-00990: missing or invalid privilege
```

In accordance to Oracle documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9013.htm#BABEFFEE

you can grant ALTER ANY TABLE (which is a powerful right) or grant ALTER privilege on particular table in another schema:

```
SQL> grant alter any table to scott;

Granted.

SQL> grant alter on hr.event to scott;

Granted.
```

Schema owner always has ALTER privilege over the objects it's owned:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_3001.htm#CJAHHIBI

"Prerequisites

The table must be in your own schema, or you must have ALTER object privilege on the table, or you must have ALTER ANY TABLE system privilege."

```
SQL> conn scott/tiger@***
Connected.
SQL> select * from session_privs;

PRIVILEGE                                                                       
----------------------------------------                                        
CREATE SESSION                                                                  
UNLIMITED TABLESPACE                                                            
CREATE TABLE                                                                    
CREATE CLUSTER                                                                  
CREATE SEQUENCE                                                                 
CREATE PROCEDURE                                                                
CREATE TRIGGER                                                                  
CREATE TYPE                                                                     
CREATE OPERATOR                                                                 
CREATE INDEXTYPE                                                                

SQL> create table t(x int);

Table created.

SQL> alter table t add (y int);

Table altered.
```