# Is it possible to add a column with alter table if the column that i'm adding has a type created by me?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

Is it possible to add a column with alter table if the column that i'm adding has a type created by me?

This is the code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE istoric IS table OF number(6,2);  
ALTER TABLE studenti ADD (history istoric) NESTED TABLE history STORE AS lista_tab;
```

I get the error :

> ORA-01031: insufficient privileges.

I already tried to grant priviliges, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37651/how-to-resolve-ora-01031-insufficient-privileges-error-on-windows-installation

Answer (score 0):

Your userid does not have the permission to alter the table. The DBA should `GRANT` your userid with the required rights via:

```
grant alter on tablename to youruserid;
```

Reference: [Oracle alter table insufficient privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639951/oracle-alter-table-insufficient-privileges)

To learn more about the privileges in Oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/authorization.htm#DBSEG99869

Comment: I solved the privileges. But now i have the error:
SQL Error: ORA-00902: invalid datatype
I know that i can CREATE TABLE with a user defined data type but i don't know if i can use ALTER TABLE to add a column with a user defined data type.

Comment: I did not experience altering a table with a user defined data type myself, but it seems yes according to some online resources I checked. See:
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0620__Object-Oriented/Altertabletoaddauserdefinedtypecolumn.htm

Comment: With the appropriate privileges you code should run.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing *special* you should do; I tested it on my Oracle 11g XE database. Apparently, all you need are `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE TYPE` privileges. Have a look at this demonstration: first, as a privileged user, I'm creating a brand new user, grant privileges to it, and then do what you're doing in your question. Works just fine.

```
SQL> create user vlad identified by sima
  2  default tablespace users
  3  quota unlimited on users;

User created.

SQL> grant create session, create table, create type to vlad;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect vlad/sima@xe
Connected.

Session altered.

SQL> create table studenti (id number);

Table created.

SQL> create type istoric is table of number(6, 2);
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> alter table studenti add (history istoric) nested table history store as lista_tab;

Table altered.

SQL>
```

So, who does table STUDENTI belong to? You, or someone else? If the latter, then yes - you might be lacking certain privileges.